# How do I return more than one item with Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to learn the basics of Scrapy. I've written the below spider to scrape one of the practice websites, [books.toscrape.com](https://books.toscrape.com). The spider scrapes the site and when I just tell it to `print` title and price it returns them for every book on the site but when I use `yield`, as below it only returns the information for the last book listed on the site.

I've no doubt my mistake's really simple but I can't work out what it is.

Can anyone tell me why this only scrapes the final title and price listing on the site?

Thanks!

```
import scrapy

class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name="CW"
start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']

def parse(self,response):
    books = response.xpath('//article[@class="product_pod"]')

    for item in books:
        title = item.xpath('.//h3/a/@title').getall()
        price = item.xpath('.//div/p[@class="price_color"]').getall()

    yield {
        'title': title,
        'price': price,
    }
```

Comment: Because `title` and `price` are overwritten in every iteration? try to ident `yield` one level right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misindented the yield:
Fixed:

```py
import scrapy

class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name="CW"
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']

def parse(self,response):
    books = response.xpath('//article[@class="product_pod"]')

    for item in books:
        title = item.xpath('.//h3/a/@title').getall()
        price = item.xpath('.//div/p[@class="price_color"]').getall()

        yield {
            'title': title,
            'price': price,
        }
```